# storing and retrieving settings in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Dont know what the problem is wether Value is not being stored or not being retrieved from isolated settings

**Page1.Xaml**

*Here I am storing data*

```
    public void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["high"] = count;
    }
```

*Here I want to retrive it!*

**Page2.Xaml**

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        TP.Text = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["high"];   
    }
```

Comment: windows phone 8? why dont you try IsolatedStorageSettings ?

Comment: We need a bit more information here.  What version of windows phone programming are you doing?  W7 phone?  W8 phone?  W8.1 silverlight?  W8.1RT?  Our answers depend on this information

Answer (score 0):

Store your data like this :

```
    public void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (!settings.Contains("high"))
        {
            settings.Add("high", count);
        }
        else
        {
            settings["high"] = count;
        }

        settings.Save();
    }
```

And then retrieve stored settings data like this :

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (settings.Contains("high"))
        {
            TP.Text = settings["high"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This type of saving data is only for "multitasking" purposes such as when user leaves your app but does not close it by back button. Also system can kill the app if it is in background and user opened another apps (I think the limit is 8 apps in background).

Your approach should work fine when app is not closed and then resumed by multitasking menu for example.

If you want to store data for long-term then use `IsolatedStorageSettings` as "Mak" answered.

You can find more info on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx